# WebService - Problemas AsynTask

Tags: java, android-studio, webservice

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class DotNetWSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    ProgressBar pg;
    String editText;
    String displayText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Name Text control
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //Display Text control
       tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        //Button to trigger web service invocation
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
        pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //Button Click Listener
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
//empty
                if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {
                    //Get the text control value
                    editText = et.getText().toString();
                    //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                    //Call execute
                    task.execute();
                    //If text control is empty
                } else {
                    tv.setText("Camp buït");

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Invoke webservice
            displayText = WebService.invokarGetempresa(editText,"KBXGetEmpresa");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Set response
            tv.setText(displayText);
            //Make ProgressBar invisible
            pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Make ProgressBar invisible
            pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

    }

}


public class WebService {

    //Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location
    private static String URL = "http://01.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/SGAWebservice.asmx?op=KBXGetEmpresa";
    //SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public static String invokarGetempresa(String aCodigoEmpresa, String KBXGetEmpresa) {
        String resTxt = null;
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, aCodigoEmpresa);
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        // Set Name
        pi.setValue("empresa");
        // Set Value
        pi.setValue(aCodigoEmpresa);
        // Set dataType
        pi.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(pi);
        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + KBXGetEmpresa, envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to resTxt variable static variable
            resTxt = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Print error
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Assign error message to resTxt
            resTxt = "Error";
        }
        //Return resTxt to calling object
        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

Creo que el problema lo tengo en el Asyn Task, pero no estoy segura. Estoy intenando consumir un webservice pero no lo consigo.

Es un webservice que tiene la siguiente consulta:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:UserCredentials>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:userName>usuarioX</tem:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:password>1234</tem:password>
      </tem:UserCredentials>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:KBXGetEmpresa>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:aCodigoEmpresa>101</tem:aCodigoEmpresa>
      </tem:KBXGetEmpresa>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

El único valor que necesito rellenar aCodigoEmpresa que yo pondre un numero: por ejemplo 201 y me devolvera el nombre de esta. 
Ambos valores son String.
También necesito poner usuario y contraseña es posible que por eso no funcione?

el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.append(KXmlSerializer.java:75)
W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.startTag(KXmlSerializer.java:442)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:660)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:645)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:702)
                  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:618)
                  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:198)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:107)
                  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:119)
                  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
                  at e.ma.myapplication.WebService.invokarGetempresa(WebService.java:43)
                  at e.ma.myapplication.DotNetWSActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(DotNetWSActivity.java:59)
                  at e.ma.myapplication.DotNetWSActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(DotNetWSActivity.java:55)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Método InvokeGetEmpresa:

```
  public static String invokarGetempresa(String aCodigoEmpresa, String KBXGetEmpresa, String password, String userName) {
        String resTxt = null;
        // Create request

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, aCodigoEmpresa);
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        // Set Name
        pi.setValue("empresa");
        // Set Value
        pi.setValue(aCodigoEmpresa);
        // Set dataType
        pi.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(pi);
        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = null;
        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + KBXGetEmpresa, envelope);
            // Get the response
            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();


            // Assign it to resTxt variable static variable
            resTxt = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Print error
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Assign error message to resTxt
            resTxt = "Error";
        }
        //Return resTxt to calling object

        return resTxt;
```

Comment: Esto ocurre en el WS ya revisaste consultando directamente el método? Puedes compartir la Url?.

Comment: Puedes compartir el método que tienes llamado `invokarGetempresa` de la clase `WebService`?.

Comment: @Andrespengineer ya estaba en el código pero lo he puesto al final del todo para que sea más visible.

Comment: He analizado la excepción y fuí a los métodos de las librerías que estas utilizando. El error ocurre, al parecer en un campo no validado de [XmlSerialize](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/xml/src/main/java/org/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer.java) en el método `setTag` al intentar hacer append en un string nulo enviado desde [SoapSerializationEnvelope](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapSerializationEnvelope.java).

Comment: En el método `writeObjectBody` se envían los parámetros a `startTag` de la siguiente manera: `writer.startTag(propertyInfo.namespace, propertyInfo.name);`. Tanto la propiedad `namespace` como `name` del objeto `PropertyInfo ` debes enviarla no nulas. Una de las dos la estas enviando nula (creo que name) y por eso se produce la excepción. Intenta setear tanto `name` como `namespace` [aqui tienes los metodos para hacerlo](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo&method=setName). Déjame saber si ya no te da la excepción para hacer una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Te funcionó la solución propuesta?